# Error 3699, creating GUID for objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to use CoCreateGuid(GUID* guid) to create a guid for objects in my application. I am getting a few errors trying to use this function.

```
error C3699: '*' : cannot use this indirection on type 'IServiceProvider' in servprov.h
error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol in servprov.h
error C2371: 'IServiceProvider' : redefinition; different basic types in servprov.h
```

Here is the code I am using, not much to it at the moment.

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "AutomationCPP.h"
#include <Rpc.h>
#include <Guiddef.h>

using namespace System;

void AutomationCPP::CustomAutomationCPP::Instantiate()
{
    long result;
    unsigned char *guidstr;
    HRESULT hr;
    GUID *UIAguid;

    CoCreateGuid(UIAguid);  //errors here
}
```

It says to use a GUID pointer for the argument but I keep getting these errors.
Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use the tags `{}` for formatting your code present on the editor window. You always have a preview of what it looks like after posting down under the editor window. Good formatting + clearly problem explanation leads to good answers.

Comment: So I put the code between {}? Good tip.

Comment: No. Write the code as usual. Once you are done select the code and then click the `{}` tag present on the editor window. This formats the code automatically for you.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks you, I was wondering how to do that. Any ideas on the question??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A using directive (`using namespace System;`) in one of your headers (probably `AutomationCPP.h`) is causing the problem.

You're indirectly including `servprov.h`, which has a definition for [`::IServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678965%28VS.85%29.aspx), and you've got the using directive which is bringing [`System::IServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider.aspx) into the global scope. This causes ambiguity for any use of `IServiceProvider` that isn't fully qualified.

Get rid of the using directive, and instead use using *declarations* only for the symbols in namespace `System` that you actually need.

Comment: When I remove system namespace from the .h file I get the following error now: Error 8 error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00001C) "extern "C" long __stdcall CoCreateGuid(struct _GUID *)" (?CoCreateGuid@@$$J14YGJPAU_GUID@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall UIAutomationCPP::CustomUIAutomationCPP::Instantiate(void)" (?Instantiate@CustomUIAutomationCPP@UIAutomationCPP@@$$FQ$AAMXXZ) UIAutomationCPP.obj

Comment: I haven't really seen many linker errors so I have no clue what this is saying... :(

Comment: @Chef : When you get a linker error for a function _you_ declared, it means you didn't provide a definition for that function. When you get a linker error for a function you _didn't_ declare (e.g. `CoCreateGuid`), it means you're not linking to the .lib file containing said function's definition, which in this case is ole32.lib (as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568(VS.85).aspx)). So in this case, add ole32.lib to your project's [linker inputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! One more thing, I included the header objbase.h as directed by the link you gave me but how do I include the ole32.dll/lib??

Comment: @Chef : The 'linker inputs' link describes how to do that.

Comment: I am trying to import it by doing: #import "Ole32.lib" but I am getting an error loading the type library (error c1083). maybe I'm not declaring it properly??

Comment: @Chef : The linked 'linker inputs' page does not mention `#import`. Follow the instructions underneath "*To add .lib files as linker input in the development environment*".

Comment: Perfect, it compiles!! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I changed #include "myclas.h" from top to bottom of includes in main and it compied!! THX!

Answer (score 0):

`UIAguid` is uninitialized.  You're supposed to provide a pointer to a buffer, like:

```
GUID UIAguid;
CoCreateGuid(&UIAguid); // address of buffer you allocated
```

But if you're using C++/CLI, why don't you use [the .NET `Guid` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)?